# How to increase displaytag table font size

Tags: css, displaytag

I'm using displaytag tables in my portlet JSPs. The tables font size is smaller than normal (everything else in the page) and I have to increase it.

The official documentation [[1](http://www.displaytag.org/10/configuration.html)] says to add some lines to the `displaytag.properties` file and reference a custom css.

This is my .properties file:

```
factory.requestHelper=org.displaytag.portlet.PortletRequestHelperFactory
basic.msg.empty_list=Nessun risultato trovato
css.tr.even=myeven
css.tr.odd=myodd
css.th.sortable=mysortable
```

and this is my .css:

```
tr.myodd {
        font-size:1.2em;
}

tr.myeven {
        font-size:1.2em;
}

th.mysortable{
        font-size:1.2em;
}
```

I also tried to define it as:

```
.myodd {
        font-size:1.2em;
}

.myeven {
        font-size:1.2em;
}

.mysortable{
        font-size:1.2em;
}
```

but without results, the displayed font is always smaller than expected.

The table is defined as:

```
<display:table class="table table-striped" [...]
```

Removing the class attribute does not change anything either, I still get small fonts. I should probably mention that both "table" and "table-striped" class values are from bootstrap [[2](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)] css

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

[[1](http://www.displaytag.org/10/configuration.html)] [Displaytag configuration]
[[2](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)] [Bootstrap CSS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by adding `style="font-size:1.2em;"` as an attribute of the display:table tag

```
<display:table style="font-size:1.2em;" [...]
```